# Errors with %include and defining library in SAS

Tags: sas

I am basically having the same issue with `%include` and defining a library.

I have the following two lines in my SASGrid program:

```
%include "\C:\Users\jhggg\Documents\SAS_Code\base.sas";
libname libr "/users/fcgdf/data/models/new_model/libr";
```

And they are resulting in the errors: `Error: Cannot open %include "sasuserhome/jhggg/\C:\Users\jhggg\Documents\SAS_Code\base.sas` and `Library libr does not exist`. I am not too sure why these are cropping up. I've read that it has to do with the actual file destinations, but `base.sas` is actually located at \C:\Users\jhggg\Documents\SAS_Code\base.sas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

```
%include "\C:\Users\jhggg\Documents\SAS_Code\base.sas";
```

On Windows, you don't want that prefixed `\`.  Change this to:

```
%include "C:\Users\jhggg\Documents\SAS_Code\base.sas";
```

If this is a Windows system, then the path for the libname will not exist.  This is a Unix/Linux path.

```
libname libr "/users/fcgdf/data/models/new_model/libr";
```

Find the actual path on the server to where that exists.

Also, you say this is a GRID job.  Make sure these paths exists on the Grid nodes.  SAS will be looking at that OS to find the files, not your local machine.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change to `%include "C:\Users\jhggg\Documents\SAS_Code\base.sas";` but I am still getting the same error with it. Im a first time user of SAS, so I am not too sure how to find the actual path on the server to where the libname exists?

Comment: As I say in my answer, if these paths are on your local machine, then they will not be found by the OS of the server.  You should talk to your system administrator to discuss where to put files for processing on the server.